# Asp Radiobuttonlist causing postback even after returning false from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

HTML:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdStatus" runat="server" Height="48px" 
  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="rad">                                                                         
    <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>                                                            
    <asp:ListItem Text="Deactive" Value="0"></asp:ListItem> 
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".rad").click(function () {
      return confirm("Do you really want to change status?");
         });
```

it always causes postback irrespective of whether I click OK or Cancel in confirmation box.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (!confirm('Do you really want to change status?')){
         return false;enter code here
    }
    else{
         return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".rad").click(function () {

                var a = confirm('Do you really want to change status?');
                
                if (a==false) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });

        




    </script>
```